# heroku config var undefined during server side rendering with Next.JS & Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, heroku, apollo-client, next.js

I have a Next.JS app with React and Apollo Client that's behaving weirdly when deployed to Heroku. The only explanation that fits what I'm seeing is that Heroku config variables aren't set early enough for doing server side rendering.

I have set a config var called API_URL (which is the address of a GraphQL API) and am using it when setting up Apollo Client, like so:

```js
import withApollo from "next-with-apollo";
import ApolloClient, { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-boost";

export default withApollo(({ ctx, headers, initialState }) => {

  // Logging to double check the API_URL
  console.log(`process.env.API_URL: ${process.env.API_URL}`);

  return new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.API_URL,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
  });
});
```

Then _app.tsx is wrapped with the withApollo-component, like so:

```js
// ...imports

class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, apollo } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ThemeProvider>
        </ApolloProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(MyApp);
```

All according to the example setup at [next-with-apollo](https://github.com/lfades/next-with-apollo).

This all works just fine on localhost, but breaks with a bunch of 501-errors when running on Heroku. The Heroku config var API_URL *has* been set (I triple checked the Heroku dashboard).

The added logging in `withApollo` shows that `process.env.API_URL` is the expected value on localhost but `undefined` when running on Heroku.

I also tried using the Next.JS `getInitialProps` function to perform server side rendering and get the same results, console logging the Heroku config var shows it's always `undefined`.

Requests made after page load does not show this behavior at all.

Finally, when using a default value for the config value everywhere, e.g. `uri = process.env.API_URL || "https://hardcoded.url/"` everything works like a charm.

Should I not expect this to work? It seems to me like Heroku just doesn't set the config variables in time to use them when doing server side rendering?

Comment: This blog post might be useful to you: https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5

Comment: @MattC Thanks for commenting! However I'm already using .env-files when developing and using Heroku's config variables when running on Heroku in this and other projects successfully, for other use cases. My problem here is config variables _when doing server side rendering_, not config variables in general.

Comment: Seems than heroku doesnt support well next.js.